# Insert Python Packages from Separate Directory into a different Namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, path, site-packages

Suppose in my Python path, I had the namespace `foo`. I have modules in a separate directory (not in the python path) called `bar`: `x.py`, `y.py`, `z.py`. So the layout might look something like this:

```
|--/python/path/site-packages/foo/ 
|----__init.py__
|--...
|--/some/other/directory/bar/
|----__init__.py
|----x.py
|----y.py
|----z.py
```

So, given that foo is already in my path, I can easily do `import foo`. However, is there any sort of black magic I can add to that `foo/__init__.py` so that in my Python shell, I can start doing something like `from foo import x` or `from foo.x import my_function`? Ideally looking for a solution that works on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6, but that isn't strict.

EDIT: I wanted to add that `bar/` could also have sub-folders or sub-packages, in the ideal scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot that I had asked this question here, but, in case anyone else ends up here, this is what I ended up doing.

```py
# /python/path/site-packages/foo/__init__.py
__path__.append("/some/other/directory/bar/")
```

The `__path__` for a particular namespace tells Python which directories that namespace should look at.